# How to find more values in one column

Tags: excel, vba, find

I don´t know how I can use "find" command.

I need to find the value of the cell "F1" in column "M". If the value is in column then copy value to the right of the value in column "M" to Worksheet "car" to cell "F2". Then go back to worksheet1 to cell "G1" and repeat until the cell "cell, row=1" is blank. If is blank then go to the next row to cell "F2"...this cycle do until the cell "F=cell, row" is blank.

See the picture:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2hoydma.jpg

I have this code but it isn´t cycle code:

```
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Find(What:=Range("F1"), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Copy
Sheets("car").Select
Range("F2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Sheets("worksheet1").Select
```

Can someone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest looking into a "for each" operation, this will iterate through your data until the column is empty link below may point you in the right direction

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I try solve that. You can modify this and can be executable.

```
Dim myRng As Range
Dim nResult As Long
Set myRng = Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("M:M")
nResult = Application.CountIf(myRng, Range("F1"))

Set rFound = Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells.Find(What:=Range("F1"), _
             After:=Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, Cells.Columns.Count), _
             LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
             SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

For i = 0 To nResult - 1


            Worksheets("car").Range("F2") = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Set rFound = Worksheets("worksheet1").Cells.FindNext(rFound)


Next i

End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, think it should do everything you wanted:

```
Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = Sheets("worksheet1").Range("F1:K14")

Dim CurrentRange As Range

    For Each CurrentRange In TargetRange

        If CurrentRange.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
        End If

        Sheets("Car").Cells(CurrentRange.Row, CurrentRange.Column) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CurrentRange.Value, Sheets("worksheet1").Range("M1:N7"), 1, False)

    Next CurrentRange
```

Comment: edited to remove some nonsense I had forgot to remove when running the code on my machine.